# Is there a keymapping reverse search in Visual Studio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

In Eclipse, you can search for the keymapping by searching for a function you know, which VS can also do, e.g., "copy".  But I can't find the opposite in VS for Eclipse's ability to search by key mapping.  Example, you can type "F3" in the search field in eclipse and find all mappings that use that function key.  Extremely useful.  Any way to do this in VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you in? VS2010 has this feature. You press the shortcut where it says 'Press shortcut keys'.

[image]

Comment: I am using VS2013.  I was looking for the upper window to auto-scroll and hi-light the matching entry.  I see now that there's a dedicated field for that.  Thanks.